# Where can I find the source code for ecore-2.2.3.jar and ecore-change-2.2.3.jar?

Tags: eclipse-emf-ecore, ecore

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question but if it's not, I'll be happy to move/delete this question.

I found the source code for both jars for versions 2.5.0 to 2.10.0 [here](http://grepcode.com/search/?r=&start=0&query=org.eclipse.emf.ecore%20change%2052.1.0&entity=project) but I can't seem to find the older versions. I've tried using a newer jar but the changes have broken code so I'm stuck with 2.2.3 for now.

Any repositories/sites to get it from would be great!

Answer (score 0):

In the oficial EMF repository you can find some tags to old versions. Not for the version that your are looking, but you can search in the repository history http://git.eclipse.org/c/emf/org.eclipse.emf.git/